# Ionic side menu: no back button on page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, navigation, angular-ui-router, parent-child

I'm struggling with such a simple thing. I have a side menu in ionic. I want the post page to be a child view of the home page. But when I navigate to the post page from the home page, the back button is missing. Also I'm not sure how to define the navbar (index.html, menu.html or post.html).

Router:

```
$stateProvider

 .state('menu', {
   url: '/menu',
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
})

 .state('menu.home', {
   url: '/home',
   views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      resolve: {authResolve: authResolve}
    }
  }
})

 .state("post", {
  url: "/home/:uid/:postId",
  templateUrl: "templates/timeline/post.html",
  controller: "PostCtrl as post",
  resolve: {authResolve: authResolve}
})
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <div>
        <div>
            <ion-nav-bar>
                <ion-nav-back-button side="left" class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c"></ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
        </div>
    </div>
```

menu.html:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
```

post.html:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-back-button side="left" class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c"></ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

the back button need to be only in the higher template (don't repeat it in the post.html). To activate the back button in post.html, the view need to be a child in menu.html template. To do that you post.html route need to be declare like :

```
.state("menu.post", { 
     url: "/post/:uid/:postId",
     views: 
         'menuContent' :{
             templateUrl: "templates/timeline/post.html",
             controller: "PostCtrl as post",
             resolve: {authResolve: authResolve}
         }
})
```

See [ionic example](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz) to understand better what happen.

Comment: The problem when I do this is that instead of the back button I get the nav icon which opens the side menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing .state('post') to .state('menu.post') to make post a sub of the menu.

Likewise, if post is a sub of home, you can chain it like menu.home.post.